# How to properly test component logic in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, frontend, vuejs3

I'm writing a new Vue project and want to test my components with vue-test-utils.
So far I've been writing unit-tests with a test case for each component method, testing its expected behavior while mocking other methods that it might call.
Recently I've read on the Vue docs that the unit tests for components should test general behavior and not rely on implemenation details:
https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/testing.html#component-testing

which makes sense, but I still want to test the logic of my component's methods.
I don't want to extract it to different files / composables because they heavily rely on the component's data and other methods, and I don't wanna pass everything as parameters.
What do you recommend regarding this?
I can't mock methods anymore since setMethods is now deprecated in vue-test-utils, which is making it harder to test each method separately.

do you think I should give up on testing each method?
I find it helpful to test methods because usually small changes make those tests fail which help me notice errors in the code, but also makes it harder because every small legitimate change requires unit-test changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have done unit test using vue-jest. Here are the steps.

1. Use the following code to set up the crypto property globally. This will allow Jest to access window.crypto and won't cause any issue.Create a `crypto.mock` file and paste following code.

   const crypto = require('crypto')

   ```
    Object.defineProperty(global.self, 'crypto', {
      value: {
        getRandomValues: arr => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length)
      }
    })
   ```
2. Now import this file in your test file component. Now You can use jasmine.Spy to spy on the elements.

   ```
    let spyFor: jasmine.Spy; spyFor = spyOn(function.hello, 'hello'); expect(spyFor).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   ```

In this way you can mock on the methods. Pls free to ask if you have anything more.

Comment: I get an error "Cannot find name 'global'".
how is this crypto related to mocking methods?